# Do static vectors need to be deleted?

Tags: c++, vector, object-lifetime, dynamic-allocation

I've been learning c++, and I'm experiencing some confusion with vectors. Specifically, if a static vector implements a dynamic array internally, will the stack memory being used by said dynamic array be released when the program ends or should I use the delete operation or call a destructor on the static vector?

Comment: When local variable goes out of scope, its destructor is called automatically. `std::vector`'s destructor will free any dynamic memory that was allocated internally by local `std::vector` object during its existence. Destructors for global objects are called likewise before program exits.

Comment: Provide a code example of "a static vector". `static` means many things in C++.

Answer (score 3):

> should I use the delete operation

If you did not allocate the thing in question using `new`, then **never** call `delete` on it.

> or call a destructor on the static vector?

If you did not re-initialize the thing in-place using placement-`new`, then **never** call a destructor explicitly.

(If you are not the person who is implementing std::vector for the standard library, then you are almost certain to never need to use placement-`new` yourself, ever.)

Global variables get cleaned up automatically at program end.

Answer (score 1):

A vector has its own internal memory management. This means that it allocates what it thinks it will need during its creation (in its constructor), and any additional memory that it will need when it needs it.

When the vector gets destroyed (either it falls out of scope or the program terminates, or it is manually deleted), all the memory that it has internally allocated gets deleted along with it.

Answer (score 0):

The destructor of the vector will be called before the program terminates.

If the vector is holding pointers to objects, their destructors will not be called, though on most platforms all memory that is allocated by a process is freed when the program terminates anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a static vector.  std::vector is an STL container that manages a resizable array (see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).  static in global context means file local so that the symbol will not be visible outside the contained compilation unit.  static in a class context is mostly a namespacing trick to create a global variable associated with a class type (as opposed to a class instance).

Whether a std::vector is static or not has nothing to do with how it is implemented.  All std::vector instances allocate and maintain the dynamically allocated contiguous array of T.  vector's destructor will delete the array of T it had previously allocated.  You neither need to allocate or free this memory, or even know that it is happening.  If your std::vector instance is static, it's destructor will be called after main() exits.  If it is allocated on the stack, its destructor will be called when it goes out of scope.  If you call

```
std::vector<T>* p = new std::vector<T>();
```

you will be responsible for calling

```
delete p;
```

before p goes out of scope.

Finally, if your vector itself contains dynamically allocated pointers, you will be responsible for deleting those as well.

```
// Not exception safe code!
std::vector<int*> v;
v.push_back(new int(4));
v.push_back(new int(5));
std::cout << *v[0] << ", " << *v[1] << std::endl;
for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter) {
    delete *iter;
}
v.clear();
```

A good rule of thumb in C/C++ is:

> That which you new, you also delete.

Since you did not new the array used by vector, you do not need to delete it.

Comment: `you will be responsible for deleting those as well.` -> proposed addition: and for making that damn thing exception safe ... ;)

Comment: hehe.. I should have noted that my example code that stores dynamically allocated pointers is NOT a good design, just illustrating the point that if you do store new'd memory, the vector class won't call delete on them for you when you call v.clear().

Answer (score -3):

All memory are released at program ends.